# How to send res.json final response in node API

Tags: node.js, ajax

Not able to send the final response once all the files deleted from filesystem.

I'm able to delete the documents but couldn't send the response.

**Error : Can't set headers after they are sent**

```
router.delete('/documents', (req, res, next) => {
    const queryParams = req.query
    var filePaths = queryParams.FilePaths.split(',')

    filePaths.forEach(getFilePath, onSuccess)

    function getFilePath(filePath) {
        const path = "\\\\cdt\\TestFolder\\" + filePath + ""
        fs.unlink(path, (error) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log("Inside error block")
                res.json({
                    status: error.status,
                    message: error.message,
                })
            }
        })
    }

    function onSuccess(data) {
        console.log("Inside On Success")
        res.json({ message: 'Documents Deleted From Shared Folder !' })
    }

})
```

Comment: `filePaths.forEach(getFilePath, onSuccess)` is this valid js syntax? `forEach` doesn't have any final callback, it's synchronous in nature.

Comment: @vatz88 Yes,it is synchronous .Not required , but I'm trying all the possibilities of callbacks & async js.Any other way of sending the final response

Comment: Just call `onSuccess` after the forEach loop? What's the issue? If there is no error in `getFilePath` it should just work. You can keep a flag to see if there was an error in `getFilePath` and based on that, call `onSuccess`. You're anyway sending response if error occurs.

Comment: Ok ! I will try that @vatz88

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are calling `onSuccess` function on each iteration. This is why you are getting the error message:

> Can't set headers after they are sent

I would call the `onSuccess` function after all operations are done. You can achieve that easily with a simple counter.